# Custom styles not working - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, xml, styles

Please note the current development is in dev mode & writing to pub/static. It is using browser sync and the sass snowdog theme for magento2.

I've got my theme running and using the **Sass** Snowdog theme, had it all running fine like so:

*Theme directory:*

> app/design/frontend/Vender/Theme/

With the snowdog themes.json file looking like so:

```
{
  "blank": {
    "src": "vendor/snowdog/theme-blank-sass",
    "dest": "pub/static/frontend/Snowdog/blank",
    "locale": ["en_US"],
    "ignore": [".test"]
  },
  "lovelane": {
    "src": "app/design/frontend/Vender/Theme",
    "dest": "pub/static/frontend/Vender/Theme",
    "locale": ["en_GB"],
    "localeOverwrites": true,
    "parent": "blank"
  }
}
```

And when I do:

`gulp styles watch browser-sync`

The files are watched inside of:

> app/design/frontend/Vender/Theme/web/css

And get written to the pub/static folder. However when i try to add these styles to the page with the following inside of:

> app/design/frontend/Vender/Theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="/web/css/mysuperstyles.css"/>
        <css src="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,700" src_type="url" />
    </head>
</page>
```

The styles don't get pulled through onto the page. Im stuck, I've run:

> bin/magento setup:di:compile

And done the static content deploy but, the files just don't load on to the page.

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: I didn't however, i could probably work it out now. Its been a while since i've touched snowdog, so i might come back to it. I'll try and post an answer today. Are you having the same issue?

Comment: I have smth similar. On my local machine it works but on the production server - does not. Files exist but i do not see styles.css in the html.